# Example of a Comet implementation in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, streaming, comet

I'm looking for an example of how to do a long running HTTP call from Flex/Actionscript to a Java server that supports Comet. Also long running http calls are usually used for pushing data from the server to the client, I would like to used for "streaming" data to the client, for example data for a large table. The client should show already some data before the call is finished. I know that LCDS from Adobe supports this, but I'm interested in a low level implementation that would get the data directly using HTTP.

Answer (score 1):

Well ... there is a [googlecode project named 'flexcomet'](http://code.google.com/p/flexcomet/source/checkout) that purports to be an implementation of the [Bayeux protocol](http://svn.cometd.org/trunk/bayeux/bayeux.html). Not played with this at all myself...

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if Blaze uses LCDS, but Blaze has the ability to do COMET:

> Publish and subscribe messaging over
>   HTTP   Publish and subscribe to
>   message topics in real time using HTTP
>   streaming or long polling (COMET) with
>   the same reliability and overall
>   quality of service as traditional
>   thick client applications, enabling
>   the creation of innovative and
>   collaborative real-time experiences.
>
> The messaging and real time
>   infrastructure, using native web
>   protocols, enables collaboration and
>   data push applications to be built in
>   a reliable manner while using native
>   web protocols, scaling to hundreds of
>   clients per CPU.Real-time examples
>   include performance monitoring,
>   real-time news feeds, and incident
>   tracking. Collaboration examples
>   include chat, assisted selling, live
>   help, and guided self-service.

(from http://labs.adobe.com/wiki/index.php/BlazeDS:Release_Notes)

You can download the turnkey distro that contains an example application to see if Blaze would meet your needs.

http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/blazeds/Release+Builds